# ASP add HTML String to preview page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webbrowser-control

I have a VB application that I am trying to convert into a ASP web application.

In my current application I write an HTML string to a webbrowser object.

In my new ASP application I don't have a webbrowser available.

What's the best way to display the generated HTML content on a "Preview" page?

This is the function I am trying to replicate:

```
Public Sub ViewHTML(ByVal DGRow As GridViewRow)

    'Display HTML in WebBrowser
    With Me.wbTest
        .Navigate("about:blank")
        If .Document IsNot Nothing Then
            .Document.Write(String.Empty)
        End If
        .DocumentText = HTML.ToString
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I suggest you start here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net/index.htm. You should really learn the basics. SO is not a site to ask for basic functionality of the aspnet framework.

Answer (score 0):

The result of an .aspx page is a HTML code which is (by IIS) delivered to a client browser which displays it. So the most simple way is just send your HTML code.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
      'your HTML creation code
      Response.Write(HTML.ToString)
      Response.End    
End Sub
```

In real world application you will want to enclose the displayed HTML to some container, but this is far beyond the scope single SO question.